# Low-level socket Error; irc.chat-Bot gives back an Attribute error

Tags: python, bots, irc

Hello fellow error searchers,

So, im trying to connect to the twitch servers with a barebone socket import because, rather than importing an module i wanna learn some basics, anyways, it terminates with an object attribution error as follows;

```
line 27, in connect
    self.irc.connect((self.irc_server, self.irc_port))
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'irc_server'
```

I just cant seem to find the error, help would be really appreciated, I'm searching since Yesterday for my mistake and it starts to reeeally hurt.

Part where error occurs;

```
def connect(self):
    self.irc = socket.socket()
    self.irc.connect((self.irc_server, self.irc_port))
    self.send_command(f"PASS {self.oauth_token}")
    self.send_command(f"NICK {self.username}")
    for channel in self.channels:
        self.send_command(f"JOIN #{channel}")
        self.send_privmsg(channel, "Hey there!")
    self.loop_for_messages()
```

Full code;

```
import socket

oauth_token = "oauth:notmyrealauthtoken"


class Bot:
    def _init__(self):
        self.irc_server = "irc.twitch.tv"
        self.irc_port = 6667
        self.oauth_token = oauth_token
        self.username = "slimkimun"
        self.channels = ["slimkimun"]


    def send_privmsg(self, channel, text):
        self.send_command(f"PRIVMSG #{channel} :{text}")


    def send_command(self, command):
        if "PASS" not in command:
            print(f"< {command}")
        self.irc.send((command + "\r\n").encode())


    def connect(self):
        self.irc = socket.socket()
        self.irc.connect((self.irc_server, self.irc_port))
        self.send_command(f"PASS {self.oauth_token}")
        self.send_command(f"NICK {self.username}")
        for channel in self.channels:
            self.send_command(f"JOIN #{channel}")
            self.send_privmsg(channel, "Hey there!")
        self.loop_for_messages()


    def handle_message(self, reveive_msg):
        print(f"> {received_msg}")


    def loop_for_messages(self):
        while True:
            received_msgs = self.irc.recv(2048).decode()
            for received_msg in received_msgs.split("\r\n"):
                self.handle_message(received_msg)


def main():
    bot = Bot()
    bot.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You'll hate this.   You are missing an underscore on `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

probably not too useful generally, but your class is not being initialized because you mispelled `__init__`

This will at least get you passed the first error:

change

```
def _init__(self):
```

to

```
def __init__(self):
```

Comment: Thank you so much my man!  It helped and resolved the error, i searched for hours yesterday. You sir are my hero for tonight, thank. :)